# Preventing quickbooks from starting on all users

Tags: windows-server-2003, quickbooks

This might be an easy question but I have to ask it.

Only three users out of 200 use quick books on term server. How can I prevent quicksbooks from starting its tray and autoupadates for each users

?
GThanks

GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup allowed applications in group policy & only set them 3 users to run quickbooks.

or remove it from system startup (probably set it in services to manual start or remove from startup folder or remove the regkey that starts it up) and use a logon script to start it for them 200 users when they login

Is this what you mean??

Comment: yeah i just want it to run for those three people.. i`ll try the msconfig option first thanks!